# How to run multiple Tor browsers with different IPs on version 9?

Tags: windows, proxy, tor, socks, torsocks

I've read This Instruction but it's outdated and I couldn't comment on it because of reputation. 
I would like to run multiple Tor Browsers all at once, with each having a unique Tor IP address.
And I'm using Windows . [ it's better to explain in different OS ]
Thanks in Advance